# What the most similar OS to RED HAT ENTERPRISE LINUX 5.3

Tags: linux, ftp, vmware, redhat-enterprise-linux

I should have a test in a few days on RED HAT ENTERPRISE LINUX 5.3 OS.

I will need to ping from one machine to another, to use FTP etc..

Since It's for my personal use and I'm not a company [I can't](https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/download/) download this non-free OS.

> My question: I'm not familiar with linux therefore I'm asking for your advise, I want to prepare myself to the exam so I want to create this exact environment in my personal PC.
>
> - Is there some way for free evaluation for this OS?
> - If not, what's the best alternative? I mean which operating system is the most similar/equivalent to perform this tasks(ping, FTP etc)

Comment: [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_(operating_system))

Comment: @IporSircer do you have idea which one? I mean Workstation/server etc

Comment: all the same, totally indifferent.

Comment: Contrary to your claim the link you include in your question clearly says that it *"...provides no-cost subscriptions for development use only."*. Thus, your are restricted from production use but not from use for testing. Also, [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) is probably the most similar thing to RHEL, it is kind of a rebranded RHEL and even the version numbers match.

Comment: The "free" version of RHEL is CentOS. But if they test you on 5.3, flee... This version is 9 years old. No sane company should be still using it. They should have at least upgraded to 5.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOS and  Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) have the same source-code base,
CentOS being released about a couple of months later.

According to
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS),
the CentOS version that relates to RHEL 5.3 is ...(surprise)... CentOS version 5.3.

You will find CentOS version 5.3 in the
[CentOS vault](http://vault.centos.org/5.3/).